# Cannot delete <0xa0> from a csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv which contains data from webpage such as the MPN and the URL. Some MPNs in the initial page have &nbsp after them.

In the csv though I see the <0xa0> which I cannot remove while I creating the csv

```
for eachitem in prods_dict[eachkey]:
    str(eachitem[0]).strip()
    if u'<0xa0>' in eachitem[0]:
        print("found")
        str(eachitem[0]).replace(u'<0xa0>',"")
        writer.writerow(eachitem)
```

how can I remove these characters from my saved csv

Comment: `replace` returns a new string, it doesn't work in-place. Same with the `str.strip()` function

Comment: If I use split()?

Answer (score 0):

Yes split() seems to clear unwanted characters in the example above I do

```
correctedlst = str(eachitem[0]).split()
eachitem[0] = correctedlst[0]
```